# Django: polls tutorial ImportError

Tags: python, django, module, frameworks

I am learning django using the app tutorial from their page. I ran into a problem with importing views.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

I think you should know that I'm doing this tutorial on Windows using PyCharm. I am importing the module from the same directory.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sarah/Desktop/django2/myproject/my_site/polls/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you registered the app in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Seems like a problem with importing, something to do with your directory structure, could you try the import using absolute path-- like `from polls.views import views`

Comment: Would be great if you could use the `tree` command to let us know the directory structure!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this in you main project url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
 path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```